# RN+Redux+Jest - Cannot test async function because file imports Store

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jestjs, react-navigation

I am developing an app that has two functions called fetchAnonymous and fetchAuthenticated that checks if the user is logged in or not. If it is not logged in, dispatches an action to logout the user to redirect to login screen. The problem is that when I import the store in this file to use the dispatch method, my tests throw errors. How can I mock it so the tests can pass?

api/base.js

```
import appStore from 'store';
import { getToken } from 'api/session';

export async function fetchAuthenticated(path, config) {
  const currentToken = await getToken();
  if (!currentToken) {
    appStore.dispatch({type: "SESSION_LOGOUT"});
    return { error: new APIError(path, {status: 401}, "missing token") };
  }

  let headers = config.headers || {};
  headers = {
    ...headers,
    Authorization: "Bearer " + currentToken
  }

  return await fetchAnonymous(path, {
    ...config,
    headers
  });
}

export async function fetchAnonymous(path, config){
  let response;
  let url = `${API_ENDPOINT}/${path}`;
  try {
    response = await fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/${path}`, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      ...config
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: new NetworkError(err.message) };
  }


  if(response.status == 401 || response.status == 403){
    appStore.dispatch({type: "SESSION_LOGOUT"});
    return { error: new APIError(path, response, 'Missing Authentication')}
  }

  if(response.status != 200 && response.status != 201 && response.status != 204){
    try {
      const json = await response.json();
      return { error: new APIError(path, response, json.error) };
    } catch (err) {
      return { error: new APIError(path, response, err.message) };
    }

  }

  try {
    const json = await response.json();
    return { response: json };
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: new APIError(path, response, err.message) };
  }


}

export class NetworkError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "NetworkError";
    this.message = message;
  }
}

export class APIError extends Error {
  constructor(path, response, message = "Try again :(") {
    super(`Unexpected response from ${path}, received ${response.status}: ${message}`);
    this.message = message;
    this.name = "APIError";
    this.status = response.status;
  }
}
```

store/index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import sagas from 'sagas';
import reducers from 'reducers';
import {
  createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware
} from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger({collapsed: true});
const navigationMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  state => state.nav,
);
const middlewares = [
  sagaMiddleware,
  navigationMiddleware
]
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === `development`) {
  middlewares.push(loggerMiddleware);
}

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
);

sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);

export default store;
```